# Is it possible to redirect subdomain but not slugs of subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am wondering if it is possible to redirect a subdomain but not any URL of the subdomain with a slug.

For instance, I want to redirect subdomain.website.com to website.com,

but I want to keep subdomain.website.com/cart at the subdomain.

The reason for this is I had Shopify at a subdomain of our site, and I need to continue using the cart, but I want to make sure that anyone that backs out of the cart does not land on my old homepage at the subdomain.

I need the subdomain for cart and checkout, but Shopify will not let me get rid of everything else and just park that stuff at a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

You may just use this rule at top of your .htaccess in site root dir:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(website\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1/ [L,R=301]
```